# How to add project as a dependency?

Tags: c#

I created the `UtilsHub` solution that contains `Utils` class, which needs to use methods from another external project `WinFormsUtils`. So I added this project to my solution

[image]

Then because of my `UtilsHub` project needs to use `WinFormsUtils` I added it as a dependency

[image]

But anyway when I try to include the dependency in a file it doesn't work

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two slightly different concepts here: dependencies and references. Project A can depend on project B for many reasons, all of which require that project B is built first.

A reference is a particular kind of dependency (and by far the most common), meaning that project be actually needs to use the contents of the project B dll in its code.

So you need to right-click on Dependencies under UtilsHub (in your first screenshot) and choose Add Reference and select WinFormsUtils to make it a full-blown reference.